# ASP UpdatePanel doesn't work when used in ContentPage

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code works fine when used in a normal webform. but when I use it in a webform using masterpages, It doesn't work.

---

page header : ~/Manager/BaseManager.master

---

and some nested master pages : Base.master > Pages.master > BaseManager.master

---

**ASP**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger EventName="Click"
              ControlID="btnUpdateEditPage" />
      </Triggers>
      <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdateEditPage" CssClass="btnUpdateEditPage" runat="server"  
     Text="Button" OnClick="btnUpdateEditPage_Click" />
```

**C#**

```
protected void btnUpdateEditPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lblTest.Text += "**";
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" - the most unhelpful phrase on stackoverflow.  What is it doing, what should it do, what error messages are you seeing (including developer tool console message)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following please:

1- Add UpdatePanel1.Update(); like the following:

```
protected void btnUpdateEditPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lblTest.Text += "**";
   UpdatePanel1.Update();
   //Your UpdatePanel should be UpdateMode="Conditional" as what you have now..
}
```

2- Put the button inside the update Panel

3- Remove the Trigger to not fire a post back, so your code has to be like:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
      <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
         <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateEditPage" CssClass="btnUpdateEditPage" runat="server"  
                Text="Button" OnClick="btnUpdateEditPage_Click" />
      </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: No luck, My problem is just when I put my updatepanel in  a contentpage with masterpages, I think maybe it depends on masterpages, they change ID of controls.

Comment: Do you have another Update panel in the content page?

Comment: no, I just create this page for test after I see this problem on my original page, when I create a webform and put this codes on it and codebehind, it works fine. but when i use a webform using masterpage, it doesn't work. my masterpage is just a simple masterpage with some Styles , no any updatepanel.

Comment: I try, but no luck :(

Comment: Please read the following article from Microsoft, this should be useful to you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398864(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Could you try to remove the trigger tag, since this will fire a submit back, and this might solve the issue.. Please look to my updated solution

Comment: Hi Salman,  I tried what I post, it is working perfectly with me, please check the other staff which might affect..

Comment: I saw it, still the trigger there man!, please remove the trigger and try again.. (Copy my staff please)

Comment: I did it, But it doesn't work again.
I remove trigger, copy your staff and change my codebehind as you told.
but not wotk

Answer (score 0):

Place the button inside UpdatePanel.

Comment: No luck, My problem is just when I put my updatepanel in  a contentpage with masterpages, I think maybe it depends on masterpages, they change ID of controls.

Comment: So place the **ClientIDMode** as **Static** for Button and all the controls in that page and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

I change

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="post">
```

to

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

and my problem solved.
But why?!